# Find: $\lim_{x→1}\frac{⁡Γ(1+x)Γ(2+x)⁡Γ(3+x)-12}{x-1}$

Tags: calculus, limits-without-lhopital

Find: $$\lim_{x→1}\frac{⁡Γ(1+x)⁡Γ(2+x)⁡Γ(3+x)-12}{x-1}$$
I can find this limit using L Hospital rule. I don 't know how to solve this without using L Hospital.Question is given by Jalil Hajimir.

Comment: Are you sure the formula is right? $\Gamma(1)=\Gamma(2)=1$ and $\Gamma(3)=2$, so the top does not go to $0$

Comment: i fixed the problem

Comment: I see 1 2 3 so not fixed yet.

Comment: Hint: Use $\Gamma(x+1)=x\Gamma(x)$

Comment: This is the just $f'(1)$ where $f(t)=\Gamma(1+t)\Gamma(2+t)\Gamma(3+t)$.

Comment: I obtained the general formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I prefer to add another answer for the general case.*

$$P_n(x)=\frac{\prod_{i=1}^n \Gamma(x+i)-\prod_{i=1}^n \Gamma(1+i)}{x-1}$$ write, using the Barnes G-function,
$$P_n(x)=\frac{G(x+1)^{n-1} G(x+2)^{-n} G(n+x+1) \Gamma (x+1)^n-G(n+2) }{x-1 }$$ Now, using
$$\frac d {dx} G(x+a)=G(x+a) \left((x+a-1)\, \psi (x+a)-(x+a)+\frac{1+\log (2 \pi )}{2} \right)$$ and L'Hospital rule or simply the derivative $P'_n(1)$  this leads to the limit
$$L_n= G(n+2) \Big((n+1) \big(\psi (n+2)-1\big)+\gamma \Big)$$ Using the identity
$$H_{n+1}=\psi (n+2)+\gamma$$ we have the general result
$$\color{blue}{L_n=G(n+2) \Big((n+1) \left(H_{n+1}-1\right)-n\,\gamma  \Big)}$$

Answer (score 6):

Consider first
$$A=\Gamma (x+1) \Gamma (x+2) \Gamma (x+3)$$ Take logarithms and use the expansion around $x=1$
$$\log (\Gamma (x+a))=\log (\Gamma (a+1))+(x-1) \psi ^{(0)}(a+1)+\frac{1}{2} (x-1)^2 \psi
   ^{(1)}(a+1)+O\left((x-1)^3\right)$$ which make
$$\log(A)=\log (12)+\left(\frac{13}{3}-3 \gamma \right) (x-1)+\left(\frac{\pi
   ^2}{4}-\frac{65}{36}\right) (x-1)^2+O\left((x-1)^3\right)$$
$$A=e^{\log(A)}=12+12 \left(\frac{13}{3}-3 \gamma \right) (x-1)+6 \left(\left(\frac{13}{3}-3 \gamma
   \right)^2+2 \left(\frac{\pi ^2}{4}-\frac{65}{36}\right)\right)
   (x-1)^2+O\left((x-1)^3\right)$$
$$\frac{A-12}{x-1}=(52-36 \gamma )+\left(91+6 \gamma  (9 \gamma -26)+3 \pi ^2\right)
   (x-1)+O\left((x-1)^2\right)$$
which shows the limit and how it is approached.

Using this truncated formula for $x=1.1$ would give $36.08$ while the exact value would be $36.68$ .

**Edit**

If we make the problem more general
$$L_n=\lim_{x→1}\Big[\frac{\prod_{i=1}^n \Gamma(x+i)-\prod_{i=1}^n \Gamma(1+i)}{x-1}\Big]$$ we have the following results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & L_n \\
 1 & 1-\gamma  \\
 2 & 5-4 \gamma  \\
 3 & 52-36 \gamma  \\
 4 & 1848-1152 \gamma  \\
 5 & 300672-172800 \gamma  \\
 6 & 277447680-149299200 \gamma  \\
 7 & 1723509964800-877879296000 \gamma \\
 8 & 83234996748288000-40452677959680000 \gamma  \\
 9 & 35395284161160806400000-16514401250259763200000 \gamma  
\end{array}
\right)$$ These sequences are not in $OEIS$.

However, it is possible to show that
$$\color{blue}{L_n=G(n+2) \Big((n+1) \left(H_{n+1}-1\right)-n\,\gamma  \Big)}$$
  where appears the Barnes G-function.